# Both square and curly brackets in a same document using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biber, biblatex-chicago

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}%
\setlength{\bibhang}{5\p@}%
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{3.5\p@}%
%\setlength{\biblabelsep}{-10\p@}%
\def\bibfont{\footnotesize}%
%\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm}
%%%
\newlength{\bibleftadd}%
\setlength{\bibleftadd}{-5\p@}%
%%
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\vspace{-2\p@}\markboth{\bibname}{\bibname}\list%
     {}%
     {\setlength{\topsep}{\z@}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\bibleftadd}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

This is for test \citet{antibayes} and \citep{pijnacker2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

%%content of test.bib%

```
@incollection{antibayes,
Address = {The Press},
Author = {G. Author1 and K. Author2 and M. Author3},
Booktitle = {The {U}niversity},
Date-Added = {2014-02-06 15:25:25 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-06 15:28:59 +0100},
Editor = {M. Editor1 and P. Editor2},
Publisher = {The {U}niversity},
Title = {The {C}ognitive {I}nterface},
Year = {2021}}

@article{pijnacker2,
Author = {J. Author4 and B. Author5 and M. Author6 and J. Author7 and P. Author8},
Date-Added = {2014-02-06 15:14:32 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-06 15:17:39 +0100},
Journal = {Journal of {T}ext},
Number = {2},
Pages = {471--480},
Title = {Study},
Volume = {23},
Year = {2010}}
```

It's working fine, but I need to change the brackets from round to square whenever the nesting style comes, example:

[image]

Here, I marked the brackets which I want to change. This was easily change by using `natbib` package, by using the tags `\setcitestyle{square}` and again revert by using the tag `\setcitestyle{round}`, is there any similar option available in `biblatex-chicago` or else any advise how to achieve my requirement? Please suggest...

Note that I'm using `MikTeX 2.9` and `biber`

Comment: It seems you have trouble moving from natbib to biblatex (also in your previous question), why not just stay with natbib?

Comment: @Marijn Sorry, it is my must requirement to use `biblatex-chicago.sty`, please suggest...

Comment: How about creating two new commands `\citetb` and `\citepb` that print Author [2021] and [Author 2021] respectively?

Comment: @Ivan Yes, you are most welcome...it should be acceptable, please suggest...Also, I need the option for all possibilities, like `\citet, \citep, \citeyear`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you don't need new commands or local settings to change the bracket style, all you need is to tell `biblatex` parentheses tracker about the outer parentheses you inserted manually.

This can be done most elegantly by not typing the outer parentheses as `(...)`, but by using the macro `\parentext{...}` instead. `biblatex` will know about the outer parentheses and switch to square brackets for the inner brackets automatically.

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
This is for test \parentext{\citet{sigfridsson} and \citep{worman}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: This is for test (Sigfridsson and Ryde [1998] and [Worman 2002])]

Comment: This what I am expecting exactly....Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 3):

You can define an alias for ever citation command and redefine locally the brackets to be used:

```
\let\citetb\citet
\let\citepb\citep
\def\switchparen{%
  \let\bibopenparen\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen\bibclosebracket}
\pretocmd{\citetb}{\switchparen}{}{}
\pretocmd{\citepb}{\switchparen}{}{}
```

**MWE**

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{antibayes,
 Address = {The Press},
 Author = {G. Author1 and K. Author2 and M. Author3},
 Booktitle = {The {U}niversity},
 Date-Added = {2014-02-06 15:25:25 +0100},
 Date-Modified = {2014-02-06 15:28:59 +0100},
 Editor = {M. Editor1 and P. Editor2},
 Publisher = {The {U}niversity},
 Title = {The {C}ognitive {I}nterface},
 Year = {2021}}

@article{pijnacker2,
 Author = {J. Author4 and B. Author5 and M. Author6 and J. Author7 and P. Author8},
 Date-Added = {2014-02-06 15:14:32 +0100},
 Date-Modified = {2014-02-06 15:17:39 +0100},
 Journal = {Journal of {T}ext},
 Number = {2},
 Pages = {471--480},
 Title = {Study},
 Volume = {23},
 Year = {2010}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\let\citetb\citet
\let\citepb\citep
\def\switchparen{%
  \let\bibopenparen\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen\bibclosebracket}
\pretocmd{\citetb}{\switchparen}{}{}
\pretocmd{\citepb}{\switchparen}{}{}


\begin{document}
 
This is for test (\citetb{antibayes} and \citepb{pijnacker2})
 
\printbibliography
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion....